# C# - Sorting controls based on their tag value

Tags: c#

I have a panel with an unknown number of controls. Each control has a tag which represents the control's rank. How do I order the controls in the panel from lowest to highest value?

For example, if I have 5 labels like so:

- label 1: Tag value = 10
- label 2: Tag value = 40
- label 3: Tag value = 2
- label 4: Tag value = 16
- label 5: Tag value = 22

How can I achieve this result:

- label 3 (**2**)
- label 1 (**10**)
- label 4 (**16**)
- label 5 (**22**)
- label 2 (**40**)

Comment: What exactly do you want to order? their position? Or their tab index?

Comment: their index inside the panel. They are docked from the top and I want them to appear in the order i specified above

Comment: Are those controls in side a list or collection?

Comment: No. They are just inside the panel

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 4):

```
var mySortedList = flpTest.Controls
.Cast<Control>()
.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag))
.ToArray();
flpTest.Controls.Clear();
flpTest.Controls.AddRange(mySortedList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using a flowLayoutPanel. Not sure how it will be affected with your setup.

```
var mySortedList = flpTest.Controls.OfType<Label>().OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag)).ToList();
flpTest.Controls.AddRange(mySortedList.ToArray());
```

The Clear may not be necessary. Removed foreach loop

Comment: Using this with a fast timer (repeating every tick) and many controls (over 50) will cause lag. Is there an alternative to using this, such as using SetChildIndex?

Comment: _fast timer_ How fast? Maybe you don't want to use all those Labels but simply Paint the texts?

Answer (score 0):

This way is a bit longer but it might be easier to understand:

1. Copy the controls into a new array
2. Sort the array by the controls' tags
3. Set the panel's controls to the ordered ones in the list

   ```
        Control[] controlArray = new Control[panel.Controls.Count];
        this.Controls.CopyTo(controlArray, 0);
        Array.Sort(
            controlArray,
            (c1, c2) => (int)c1.Tag - (int)c2.Tag
            );
        panel.Controls.Clear();
        panel.Controls.AddRange(controlArray);
   ```